# Trouble finding conjugate transpose of differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials with degree less than or equal to $3$. Let $V$ have the inner product, $$\langle f|g\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\,dt.$$ Let $D$ be the differentiation operator on $V$. Find $D^{*}$.

(Note that $V$ is finite-dimensional.)

I'm confused. I can get a matrix for $D$ in the standard basis and take the conjugate transpose of that to find $D^{*}$. But then I'm not using the inner product, and am restricting myself to work in a fixed basis. I'm not sure what exactly the question is asking me to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of $D^*$ in your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the method you are thinking of, but perhaps this shows you how one typically uses the inner product to find adjoints.

We define the adjoint operator $D^*$ of $D$ as the operator satisfying
\begin{equation}
\langle Df, g \rangle = \langle f, D^* g\rangle
\end{equation}
for all $f,g \in V$.

So, notice that given any $f,g\in V$ we have
\begin{align}
\langle Df,g\rangle &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} f(t) g(t) dt\\
&= -\int_0^1 f(t) \frac{d}{dx}g(t) dt + f(1)g(1)-f(0)g(0).
\end{align}
We can write the boundary terms using delta functions as 
$$
f(1)g(1) = \int_0^1 \delta(t-1)f(t)g(t)dt
$$
and
$$
f(0)g(0) = \int_0^1 \delta(t)f(t)g(t)dt
$$
so that overall we have
$$
\langle Df,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(t)\left(-\frac{d}{dx} +\delta(t-1)-\delta(t)\right)g(t)dt.
$$
Thus, the adjoint operator is
$$
D^* = -\frac{d}{dx} + \delta(t-1)-\delta(t).
$$